# events.js:288 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, npm, angular9, typescript2.7

I got the error while doing build in Angular 9.1.0 version.

```
npm run build
```

I got bellow error,

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.target._send (internal/child_process.js:806:20)
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:677:19)
    at ChildProcessWorker.send (D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:330:17)
    at WorkerPool.send (D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\WorkerPool.js:32:34)
    at Farm._process (D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:129:10)
    at Farm._enqueue (D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:152:10)
    at Farm._push (D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:159:12)
    at D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:90:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Farm.doWork (D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:56:12)
    at JestWorker._callFunctionWithArgs (D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\index.js:178:23)
    at TaskRunner.runTask (D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js:41:26)
    at enqueue (D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js:80:35)
    at D:\PublishSource\sample\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js:104:86
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at internal/child_process.js:810:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  errno: 'UNKNOWN',
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'write'
```

Comment: It's related to memory/cpu usage of terser-webpack-plugin (that use jest-worker for parallelism). Some infos about it : https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#parallel and https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso/pull/39535#issuecomment-589603920

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, tried again without changes and it worked...